# ionic/in-app-purchase 2 can't get product information AGAIN after exit view

Tags: ios, angular, in-app-purchase, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4/Angular and developing the in-app purchase. I am following the online tutorial: https://enappd.com/blog/how-to-in-app-purchase-in-ionic-4-apps-ios/99/.

I can use `store.refresh()` and then `store.get()` to get the detailed product information from the Apple server for the first view (my purchasing page). However, when I exit the purchasing page and re-enter again, I am no longer able to get detailed product information (price, description, etc.) again. I have to wait for a long time, logout and login again before I can get the price/description information again.

Anybody know why and how to fix it? Thanks.

P.S. I asked this question to enappd.com a few weeks ago but it seems they have no clue as well.